# TypeError: Cannot read property 'onReady' of undefined

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

When I run `node ./myapp.js`, I'm getting

```
(node:14122) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637
      module.reflect.onReady((reflect) => {
                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'onReady' of undefined
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:22)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:558:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:663:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ecarroll/code/sw/source-water/sw-input/node_modules/psl/index.js:14:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:734:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:12)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kicker here is,

> (node:14122) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.

This and the subsequent type error

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'onReady' of undefined
> ```

Are caused by the presence of,

```
NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-modules
```

You should undefine that or set it `NODE_MODULES="" node ...`

[If you run Node with --experimental-modules then,](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18442#issuecomment-333732236)

> It's important to note here that `.mjs` isn't only about file extensions. running node with the
>   `--experimental-modules` flag also means that ES6 module specifiers [*must be valid urls*](http://2ality.com/2017/05/es-module-specifiers.html#how-do-module-specifiers-change-with-esm), so the extension has to be included in the import statement, e.g. `import x from './x.mjs`